# get_query_var not working for subdirectory

Tags: directory, query-variable

I am using this code `$pagename = get_query_var('pagename');` to get page name. Its working fine on localhost install under root directory. But when I have moved wordpress to run under subdirectory it returns no value

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use `get_query_var` for getting the pagename (slug) - there is no guarantee that `pagename` will be set, depending on your permalink structure (or lack thereof).

Instead, check if the request is for a page, and then get the slug directly from the queried object:

```
if ( is_page() ) {
     $slug = get_queried_object()->post_name;
}
```